# Could not switch to this profile proxy 0: filed ws-opts.headers[Host] invalid: Clash for windows

Tags: vpn, proxy

I'm trying to use [`Clash for windows`](https://github.com/Fndroid/clash_for_windows_pkg/releases) which is a rules-based, cross-platform proxy application core program written in Go, and it's a graphical Clash branch available on Linux. ([Reference](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.Fndroid.clash_for_windows))

I have a `Vmess` account which is working pretty fine on my iphone via the [`NapsternetV`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.napsternetlabs.napsternetv&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1) application, but I wanted to use it on my windows pc, so I downloaded `Clash for windows`.

However, in order to use the `Vmess` account it should be converted to `yaml` or `yml` file in a way which is interpretable via the `Clash for Windows`.

So I found a [website](https://blog.fastssh.com/clash/how-to-use-clash-on-windows/) which had a documentation to convert the `Vmess` accounts to profiles of `Clash for Windows` with another [website](https://sshkit.com/subconverter/).

I've followed those instructions, but I ended up with following error:
`Could not switch to this profile proxy 0: filed ws-opts.headers[Host] invalid`

This is the `profile` I imported:

```
port: 7890
socks-port: 7891
redir-port: 7892
mixed-port: 7893
mode: rule
log-level: silent
allow-lan: true
external-controller: 0.0.0.0:9090
bind-address: "*"
ipv6: false
dns:
  enable: true
  ipv6: false
  enhanced-mode: redir-host
  listen: 0.0.0.0:7894
  fallback-filter:
    geoip: false
    ipcidr:
    - 240.0.0.0/4
  nameserver:
    - https://puredns.org/dns-query
    - tls://puredns.org:853
  fallback:
    - tcp://108.137.44.39
    - tcp://108.137.44.9
    - 108.137.44.39
    - 108.137.44.9
tun:
  enable: true
  stack: system 
  macOS-auto-route: true
  macOS-auto-detect-interface: true
  dns-hijack:
    - tcp://108.137.44.39:53
experimental:
  interface-name: en0

proxies:
  - {name: E, server: it.esimasi.shop, port: 2095, type: vmess, uuid: 068decc2-6ac5-4570-9059-72266dd55839, sni: , alterId: 0, cipher: auto, tls: , skip-cert-verify: true, udp: true, network: ws, ws-opts: {path: /, headers: {Host: }}}

proxy-groups:
  - name: sshkit-generator
    type: select
    proxies:
      - E

rules:
 - MATCH,sshkit-generator
```

I have no idea what I should do with this error, I appreciate any help :)